# HTTP Logging in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know of a plugin / gem that will log any HTTP requests your rails app may be making when responding to a request?  For example if you are using HTTParty to hit an API, how can you see what outbound requests are coming out of your rails app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to tell the outbound HTTP client to use a proxy.

For HTTParty it's fairly simple (from the [docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods)),

```
class Twitter
    include HTTParty
    http_proxy 'http://myProxy', 1080
```

If you're looking for a proxy to set up, personally I like [Paros proxy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/paros/) (Java so cross platform and does SSL).

Answer (score 6):

Try also http_logger gem:

```
require 'http_logger'

Net::HTTP.logger = Logger.new(...) # defaults to Rails.logger if Rails is defined
Net::HTTP.colorize = true # Default: true
```

This will log all requests that goes through Net::HTTP library.

https://github.com/railsware/http_logger

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing development on your own machine, Charles Proxy is a good option.

In production, you'd probably be better off creating your own logger.debug() messages.

Comment: I've been using Charles and it doesn't seem to log any of the calls to external apis using HTTParty

Answer (score 1):

The only way I got this to work was to specify only the IP as the first parameter to the `http_proxy` call:

```
http_proxy '10.2.2.1', 8888
```

The example above, with the http:// prefix, did not work, I got a `SocketError: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided`

Answer (score 1):

Try my [httplog](https://github.com/trusche/httplog) gem, you can customize it to log requests, responses, headers etc.